# Compare counts between two tables even when one of the tables has no record in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am stuck in a difficult situation. I need to compare the counts of 2 and update one of the tables based on the comparison. Below are the details:

I have 2 tables: dwh_idh_to_iva_metadata_t and lnd_sml_price_t.
Every day there is a package running that loads data from source table dwh_sml_price_t to destination table lnd_sml_price_t. This package also checks the counts between the tables "dwh_idh_to_iva_metadata_t" and "lnd_sml_price_t". If the counts are matching then it updates few columns in the table dwh_idh_to_iva_metadata_t and if the counts are not matching then the package throws an exception and exits. To do the count comparison we created a cursor and then fetching that cursor for comparison. The code for cursor is as follows:

```
CURSOR C_CNT_PRICE IS
     SELECT
        lnd.smp_batchrun_id batch_id,
        lnd.lnd_count,
        dwh.dwh_count
     FROM
        (
          SELECT
            smp_batchrun_id,
            COUNT(*) lnd_count
          FROM
            iva_landing.lnd_sml_price_t
          GROUP BY
            smp_batchrun_id
        ) lnd
     LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            batchrun_id,
            sent_records_count dwh_count,
            dwh_sending_table
        FROM
        dwh.dwh_idh_to_iva_metadata_t
        ) dwh ON dwh.batchrun_id = lnd.smp_batchrun_id
        WHERE
        dwh.dwh_sending_table = 'DWH_SML_PRICE_T'
    ORDER BY
    1 DESC;    `
```

And the actual code for comparison is:

```
`    FOR L_COUNT IN C_CNT_PRICE LOOP       --0001,0002
          IF L_COUNT.lnd_count = L_COUNT.dwh_count THEN
            UPDATE DWH.DWH_IDH_TO_IVA_METADATA_T idh
            SET idh.IVA_RECEIVING_TABLE = 'LND_SML_PRICE_T',
            idh.RECEIVED_DATE = SYSDATE,
            idh.RECEIVED_RECORDS_COUNT = L_COUNT.lnd_count,
            idh.status = 'Verified'
            WHERE L_COUNT.batch_id = idh.batchrun_id
            AND idh.dwh_sending_table = 'DWH_SML_PRICE_T';
            COMMIT;
          ELSE
            RAISE  EXCPT_MISSDATA;  -- Throw error and exit process immediately
          END IF;
       END LOOP;    `
```

Now, the problem is that there may be certain cases when the table "LND_SML_PRICE_T" is not having any data, in which case, DWH_IDH_TO_IVA_METDATA_T should have the columns updated as in case of matching counts.

I need help in modifying the code so that comparison is done even in case of no records in LND_SML_PRICE_T table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there are no rows in `LND_SML_PRICE_T` table, cursor `C_CNT_PRICE`'s `LND_COUNT` equals `0` which means that comparison code should be modified to

```
FOR L_COUNT IN C_CNT_PRICE LOOP
      IF (L_COUNT.lnd_count = L_COUNT.dwh_count) 
         or L_COUNT.lnd_count = 0                     --> this
      THEN
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The cursor above is using the condition: "ON dwh.batchrun_id = lnd.smp_batchrun_id". So can I use the condition that you mentioned "L_COUNT.lnd_count = 0 " ?

Comment: This condition is related to column value cursor returns, so - why couldn't you use it? It isn't related to join condition in the cursor.